# show/hide select html5 javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i search in this forum and and tried different ways explained right here ,i tried everything but i have this problem, as you can see i tried diferent ways, the function show me the alert....but does't hide or show anything, and i don't know why :/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function show(valor) {
  var zona1=document.getElementById("zona");
  var b=document.getElementById("barrioscf");
  var part=document.getElementById("partidos");

  if (valor==1) {
    /* b.style.visibility='visible';
       part.style.visibility='hidden';
    */
    b.style.display = 'block';
    part.style.display = 'none';

    alert ("entro if 1");
    //document.all.form_crea.barrioscf.style.visibility="visible"
    //document.all.form_crea.p.style.visibility="hidden"

  } else if(valor==2) {
    b.style
    b.style.display = 'none';
    part.style.display = 'block';

    alert ("entro if 2");

    /* b.style.visibility="hidden";
       part.style.visibility="visible";*/
    //document.all.form_crea.barrioscf.style.visibility="hidden"
    //document.all.form_crea.p.style..visibility="visible"
  }
}
</script>


<select id="zona" name="zona_nombre" 
 onChange="javascript:mostrar_barrios(this.value);">
  <option value="1">Capital Federal</option>
  <option value="2">Gran Buenos Aires</option>
</select>

<tr><td>Barrios:
  <td>
    <select id="barriocf"name="barriocf" >
      <?
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
          echo "<option value='".$row['0']."'>".$row['1']."</option>";
        } 
        mysql_free_result($result); 
      ?> 
    </select>
<tr id="partidos">
  <td>Partidos:
  <td>
    <select id="p"name="partido" style="visibility:hidden">
      <option value="Avellaneda">Avellaneda</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: To begin with, your HTML is not valid. You need close tags for your `tr` and `td` elements. I do not see a `table` tag, but it would need a close tag as well. Also, at the bottom you have `id="p"name="partido"` - there should be a space between the attributes. I see a `show(valor)` function as well, but I don't see where it's being called.

Comment: @Zhihao—closing tags for TR and TD are optional. Note the example in the HTML5 [thead](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-thead-element) section doesn't have closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

well your block structure comment structure and the id of the select element are wrong please take a look at this one.

1. table tags added
2. function name changed to show
3. comments removed.
4. second if blocked corrected and `b.style` line removed.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dg8wR/

the rest is in your hands.